# How to use Powershell in VScode to implement GCC build C source file on Window?

Tags: c, powershell, gcc, window

I want to use command line: gcc {filename.c} -o {filename.exe} to compile source code but the real directory is too long, I need a way to minimize it, I need some guide if someone else faced the same problem. Below is my implementation. I'm coding on Window.

```
PS E:\CodingWorkspace\VScodeC> gcc LinkedList.c -o LinkedList.exe
gcc.exe: error: LinkedList.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
```

I'm expecting a built LinkedList.exe and run it in Terminal Powershell

Comment: Is this Windows PowerShell? Try running `[System.Environment]::CurrentDirectory = "$PWD"` after navigating to `E:\CodingWorkspace\VScodeC`, but before running `gcc`

Comment: Is LinkedList.c in current directory?

Comment: Yes, LinkedList.c is in current directory

Comment: It was missing a directory in the terminal, which cause the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, I have a folder in which store another folder that contains the file.c I need to run, but the terminal is open with the directory of the external folder, not the last folder that contains the file. This is the adjusted terminal code. It worked
`PS E:\CodingWorkspace\VScodeC\1000BaiCode> gcc Stack.c -o Stack`
`PS E:\CodingWorkspace\VScodeC\1000BaiCode> ./Stack`